# Executing php script in command line using only file name and no php command

Tags: php, command-line, shellexecute, command-line-arguments

How can I configure linux/php to run php scripts without having to type the php -f command everytime I want to run a script. 
i.e.

Instead of:

```
$ php -f /path/to/file/script.php
```

I would like for the script to run when I do just this:

```
/path/to/file/script.php
```

My google-fu has failed me in this regard, and mostly all other SO questions regarding running php from the command line don't really help.  Our remote server at work does this, and I'm a little baffled by how it's done. I'm thinking something to do with the .php extension? No hash-bangs are used either in any php file.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make your `script.php` executable with `chmod +x /path/to/file/script.php`
2. Put path to the php interpreter in the first line like `#!/path/to/php`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I stated above, there are no hash-bangs in any of the files on the server where i'm able to do this.

Comment: @John: I highly doubt there is any other easy solution

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can get is by setting up an alias for 'php -f':
*alias zz="php -f "*

You should now be able to use:
zz /path/to/file/script.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could do this without using a hash-bang/shebang.  The only ideas that come to mind are configuring the shell to treat files ending in .php specially, or telling the kernel how to execute these files, as it does with ELF format binaries (I think this feature used to be used to launch DOS .exe files directly, without needing to specify the name of the emulator.)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
alias /path/to/file/script.php='php -f /path/to/file/script.php'
```

Answer (score -1):

put this lines into first line of your script :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
```

after run this command:

```
chmod 0755 yourscript.php
```

then you can run ./yourscript.php